# OOJS - Binding each element to a specific click

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm slowly trying to slug my way through learning OOJS by building an accordion toggle and I'm having a hard time.

EDIT: Slowly getting there. I've got the toggle functioning how I want to. Unfortunately I'm calling the add / remove class incorrectly(?).

I'm currently calling it like:

```
accordion.ELEMENTS.TRIGGER.click(function() {
 if ($(this).parent().hasClass(accordion.CLASSES.OPEN)){
  $(this).parent().removeClass('open')
 }
 else {
  $(this).parent().addClass('open');
 }
});
```

And I would rather call it via the `EVENTS.OPEN` & `EVENTS.CLOSE` or even throw both of this into the `EVENTS.BIND` and have BIND sort out whether or not if it is open or not :

[Here's a JSFiddle, I'm trying to bind the EVENTS.OPEN and EVENTS.CLOSE instead of trying to find the parents.](http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/Ln85bfn5/145/)

```
var accordion = { 
    ELEMENTS: {
        HOME:        $('.js-accordion-toggle'),
        TRIGGER:     $('.js-accordion-trigger'),
        PANEL:       $('.js-accordion-panel')
    },

    CLASSES: {
        OPEN: 'open'
    },

    EVENTS: {                   
        OPEN: function() {
            if (ELEMENTS.HOME.hasClass(accordion.CLASSES.OPEN)) {
                console.log(this + "open");
                ELEMENTS.HOME.addClass(accordion.CLASSES.OPEN);
            }
            else {
                console.log("this should close");
                this.close();
            }
        },

        CLOSE: function() {
           accordion.ELEMENTS.HOME.removeClass(accordion.CLASSES.OPEN);
        },

        //BIND: function() {
        //    accordion.ELEMENTS.HOME.each(function() {
        //        accordion.EVENTS.OPEN();
        //    });
        //}
    },
    fn: {
        attachEvents: function() {
            accordion.ELEMENTS.TRIGGER.click(function() {
               console.log(this);
                if ($(this).parent().hasClass(accordion.CLASSES.OPEN)){
                    $(this).parent().removeClass('open')
                }
                else {
                    $(this).parent().addClass('open');
                }
            });                 
        }
    },

    init: function() {

        accordion.fn.attachEvents();
    }        
}


accordion.init();
```

Comment: I think you are very close. If I understood your codes correctly, don't you need to invoke `accordion.init()` to trigger the event binding? And then I have to replace your line 37 with             `accordion.ELEMENTS.PANEL.addClass(accordion.CLASSES.OPEN);` to get the click-event binding to work.

Comment: @isim I ditched the EVENTS.OPEN and EVENTS.CLOSE and it seems to be working. Not the most eloquent, but I guess it works out =/ http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/Ln85bfn5/180/

Comment: I personally like single concept like toggling (like what you did) then (multiple) symmetrical concepts like "open and close", "fold and unfold", "expand and collapse" etc..

Comment: In this situation I like the solution. It was more for practice than anything else. I guess I would like to be able to use the same solution in other situations. Such as when something acts different at different break points. Toggle on mobile, tabs on tablet. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get your original [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/Ln85bfn5/104/) to work by invoking `accordion.init()` after your object definition. I also had to replace your line 37 with `accordion.ELEMENTS.PANEL.addClass(accordion.CLASSES.OPEN);` to get rid of some `undefined object` error.

As for your new [codes](http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/Ln85bfn5/180/), you can simplify your codes by removing the `if..else` statement in line 19 and 22 with [`jQuery.toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/), to make it looks like:

```
$(this).closest(toggleHome).toggleClass(toggleClass);
```